# How to access object properties from prototype in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have class below when I call printData I get this.collection is undefined.

How do I access this.collection from the prototype inside printData()? Or do i need to change the class structure. Actually the object returns function which intern returns object in hierarchy.

Thanks in advance!

Sample Class:

```
var DbProvider = (function () {
    function DbProvider(db) {
        var that = this; // create a reference to "this" object
        that.collection = db;
    }
    DbProvider.prototype.create = function () {
        return {
            action: function () {
                var y = {
                    printData: function () {
                        alert('Hello ' + this.collection.Name);
                    }
                };
                return y;
            }
        };
    };
    return DbProvider;
})();
```

Usage:

```
var a = new DbProvider({ "Name": "John" });
a.create().action().printData();
```

Comment: Would it be possible to use ES6 classes?

Comment: In your code, you create a reference to `this`, labeled in `that`. Could you use `that` instead (pun not intented)

Comment: no that object is not accessible. Also is it possible to create with plain javascript with ES5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save the `this` reference and bind it to the `printData` function

```js
var DbProvider = (function () {
    function DbProvider(db) {
        var that = this; // create a reference to "this" object
        that.collection = db;
    }
    DbProvider.prototype.create = function () {
        var self = this;
        return {
            action: function () {
                var y = {
                    printData: function () {
                        alert('Hello ' + this.collection.Name);
                    }.bind(self)
                };
                return y;
            }
        };
    };
    return DbProvider;
})();

var a = new DbProvider({ "Name": "John" });
a.create().action().printData();
```

Or you could refactor a bit and move `that` to the outer scope  of `DbProvider` and use `that` in `printData`

```js
var DbProvider = (function () {
    var that;
    function DbProvider(db) {
        that = this; // create a reference to "this" object
        that.collection = db;
    }
    DbProvider.prototype.create = function () {
        return {
            action: function () {
                var y = {
                    printData: function () {
                        alert('Hello ' + that.collection.Name);
                    }
                };
                return y;
            }
        };
    };
    return DbProvider;
})();

var a = new DbProvider({ "Name": "John" });
a.create().action().printData();
```

Answer (score 1):

Keeping ES5 syntax and the call structure a solution would be:

```
var DbProvider = (function () {
    function DbProvider(db) {
        var that = this; // create a reference to "this" object
        that.collection = db;
    }
    DbProvider.prototype.create = function () {
        var that = this;
        return {
            action: function() {
                var y = {
                    printData: function () {
                        console.log('Hello ' + that.collection.Name);
                    }
                };
                return y;
            }
        };
    };
    return DbProvider;
})();
```

Definitely not elegant but it works :)

If you do not want to change your structure, you can achieve this behavior if you change you functions to [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

```
var DbProvider = (function () {
    function DbProvider(db) {
        var that = this; // create a reference to "this" object
        that.collection = db;
    }
    DbProvider.prototype.create = function() {
        return {
            action: () => {
                var y = {
                    printData: () => {
                        alert('Hello ' + this.collection.Name);
                    }
                };
                return y;
            }
        };
    };
    return DbProvider;
})();
```

The way you are creating this "class" is definitely non standard. Let me know if you want an example of how to better structure it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I am looking for ES5  solution? Is it possible to achieve in ES5? Also please advise if I can restructure the class without changing final caller part i.e.dbProvider.create().action().printData();

Answer (score 1):

just need to keep track of the this pointer correctly, like this

```js
var DbProvider = (function() {
  function DbProvider(db) {
    this.collection = db;
  }
  DbProvider.prototype.create = function() {
    var self = this;
    return {
      action: function() {
        var y = {
          printData: function() {
            alert('Hello ' + self.collection.Name);
          }
        };
        return y;
      }
    };
  };
  return DbProvider;
})();



let dbProvider = new DbProvider({
  Name: "test"
});
dbProvider.create().action().printData();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I am looking for ES5 solution? Is it possible to achieve in ES5/simple javascript? –

Comment: updated - no es6 class